# How to automatically exclude items already visited in recommendation algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recommendation-engine

I'm now using [slope One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_One) for recommendation.

How to exclude visited items from result?

I can't do it simply by `not in (visited_id_list)` to filter those visited ones because it will have scalability issue for an old user!

I've come up with a solution without `not in`：

```
select b.property,count(b.id) total from propertyviews a
                                         left join propertyviews b on b.cookie=a.cookie
                                         left join propertyviews c on c.cookie=0 and b.property=c.property
                                         where a.property=1 and a.cookie!=0 and c.property is null
                                         group by b.property order by total;
```

Comment: Are you implementing this in SQL? If not, how is your data even stored? If you're pulling in all of the data, processing it, and then presenting it... then you have larger problems.

Comment: Yes,I'm implementing it in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, if you are using MySQL, look at [12.2.10.3. Subqueries with ANY, IN, and SOME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

For example:

```
SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 IN    (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
```

This is available in all versions of MySQL I looked at, albeit that the section numbers in the manual are different in the older versions.

**EDIT** in response to the OP's comment:

1. OK ... how about something like `SELECT id FROM t1 WHERE ... AND NOT id IN (SELECT seen_id FROM user_seen_ids where user = ? )`.  This form avoids having to pass thousands of ids in the SQL statement.
2. If you want to entirely avoid the "test against a list of ids" part of the query, I don't see how it is even possible in theory, let alone how you would implement it.